Cannot connect custom data model object with standard data model object
I have a custom data model object appointments and I am trying to connect it to the standard data model object Individual.
However, this doesn't seem to be possible, since the dropdown for the field is empty.
Is there any bug in the Data Cloud mapping interface?

In my case, the problem was with matching data types.
In the source system, system identifiers are defined as numbers and have number types.
However, standard data model object has Id and ExternalId field defined as text types.
This means it is required either to modify the custom model definition from number to text or define a custom Number field on standard data model object to match.
